Vite drop console.log but keep console.error on esbuild
I want to remove the console.logs in the build but don't want to remove the console.errors, is there a way to do this?
This is what I currently have.
    esbuild: {
      drop: mode === 'production' ? ['console', 'debugger'] : undefined
    },

This is also drops the console.errors.
Do I need to create a plugin or a rollup?

You can try with:
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  return {
    // other configuration
    esbuild: {
      pure: mode === 'production' ? ['console.log'] : [],
    }
  }
}

Came from github issue
